# Difference in Time complexity of Loops

Tags: java, performance, loops, time-complexity

The reason for posting this question [comes from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183108/need-help-improving-my-vba-loop/25183523#comment39213666_25183523)

Is there any `Time complexity` difference between the following Snippets of Code?

### Code Snippet A:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++) {
                if (i < 100)
                    System.out.println("Hi");    
            }    
        }    
    }
```

### Code Snippet B:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
            if (i < 100)
                System.out.println("Hi");    
        }    
    }
```

The Difference in code between the two is that `Snippet B` doesn't contain the inner loop from `Snippet A` which doesn't serve any purpose hence removed.

### My assumptions:

Both `Snippet A:`  and `Snippet B:` takes O(n) for large values of n

There could be some differences in `space complexity` since we have another loop variable `j` in `Snippet A`

### Observation:

I tested the similar version of this loop structure in `VBA` and the `Snippet B` is a little faster than `Snippet A`

Is it because of space or time complexity differences or both?

Comment: Well in A you have to do a string concatenation which is not there in B.

Comment: A also has an inner loop.

Comment: I'm not actually seeing any "n". Is "n" you're referring to for the purposes of time complexity the 10 in the outer for loop?

Comment: @vandale: I updated the question to print same output @Mshnik: Yes for large values of `n` in the loop

Comment: Please don't confuse "execution time" or "performance" with "time complexity".  If _n_ is the number of input data items, and you have one algorithm that takes about 0.001 * _n_ seconds to run and another that takes 10 * _n_ seconds to run, they both have the same time _complexity_ (linear, or O(_n_)), but of course one is ten thousand times slower.

Comment: @ajb I do understand the difference , but isn't the purpose of finding time complexity , is ultimately to figure out which piece of code runs faster!

Comment: Not really.  If you're deciding between two totally different algorithms, and one runs in O(_n_), say, and the other in O(_n_ log _n_), then you can determine that the first one will run faster _for sufficiently large n_.  We use this to evaluate sorting algorithms, for instance.  But in real life, the basic algorithm is usually settled early on, and the performance is based on other factors besides "time complexity".

Comment: By the way, the question that you just linked to has nothing to do with "time complexity".  I think you're just misusing the term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TECHNICALLY**, both of your examples run in constant time.

If you were to switch your first for loop to count up to N or some variable, then they would both run in O(N).  There is no difference in time complexity since then they would both be O(N) plus a constant time operation, resulting in just O(N).

The reason code snippet A is slower is because there is still a loop overhead (incrementing and comparing j).

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant when you say `If you were to switch your first for loop to count up to N or some variable` ?

Comment: @firephil There is no `n` in either one. Both of them run a fixed number of times (10 times) through the loop.

Comment: Since your loop always counts to 10, technically that runs in constant time.  If your loops counted up to some variable or function parameter, then it would be O(N).

Answer (score 1):

The overhead from intializing, comparing, and incrementing j would slow A, but I don't see a practical application for the inner loop. 

This would definitely be shot down in production code since it reduces readability.